# Incase a user imports a schema from a database then does HCL OneTest Data support the generation of data for BLOB data type?

Tags: types, import, dataset, blob, schema

When a user imports the schema or sample data set from the database then will HCL OneTest Data generate the data for BLOB data type?

Answer (score 0):

No, as of now, HCL OneTest Data cannot generate the test data for the BLOB data type.